# Pandas columns to array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with the following structure:

```
date      country  value

20200215  Austria  123.32
20200215  Finland  321.21
20200216  Austria  123.32
20200216  Finland  321.21
```

What I like to achieve is this:

```
date     CountryValue

20200215  ['Austria':123.32,'Finland':321.21]
20200216  ['Austria':123.32,'Finland':321.21]
```

I don't manage to get a solution, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `What I like to achieve is this:`, can you specify what type of data structure you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want dictionaries use `zip` with `dict` per groups in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) in lambda function:

```
f1 = lambda x: dict(zip(x['country'], x['value']))
df1 = df.groupby('date')['country','value'].apply(f1).reset_index(name='CountryValue')
print (df1)
       date                            CountryValue
0  20200215  {'Austria': 123.32, 'Finland': 321.21}
1  20200216  {'Austria': 123.32, 'Finland': 321.21}
```

If want lists use flattening lists in list comprehension:

```
f2 = lambda x: [z for y in x.values for z in y]
df2 = df.groupby('date')['country','value'].apply(f2).reset_index(name='CountryValue')
print (df2)

       date                        CountryValue
0  20200215  [Austria, 123.32, Finland, 321.21]
1  20200216  [Austria, 123.32, Finland, 321.21]
```